# To get sum of all child entries of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have OrderCart from where I want to get sum of all the item prices so that it displays total price to the user

this is my Order class which has string price attribute

```
public class Order {
private String mID;
private String mName;
private String mPrice;
public Order(){

}


public Order(String id, String name, String price)
{
    mID = id;
    mName = name;
    mPrice = price;
}



public String getmID() {
    return mID;
}

public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}

public String getmPrice() {
    return mPrice;
}
```

and this is class where firebase adopter to retrieve data is present. The adopter displays all the children under OrderCart parent and total sum should be display below the adopter but it is giving errors

```
public class PlaceOrder extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mOrderList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private int total_amount=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_orders);

    mOrderList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.order_layout);
    mOrderList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mOrderList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OrderCart");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, OrderViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, OrderViewHolder>(
            Order.class,
            R.layout.single_order,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase


    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Order model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setmID(model.getmID());
            viewHolder.setmName(model.getmName());
            viewHolder.setmPrice(model.getmPrice());


        }
    };

    mOrderList.setAdapter(FBRA);

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapScore : dataSnapshot.child("OrderCart").getChildren()) {
                total_amount += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(snapScore.child("mPrice").getValue()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    TextView item_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
    item_price.setText(total_amount);

}
```

now when I try to display total amount, the app collapse so how can I properly retrieve the data?

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.eaton/com.example.android.eaton.PlaceOrder}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, use iterator to read the data.

Inside  onDataChange,

```
Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotsorder =  dataSnapshot.child("OrderCart").getChildren().iterator();
  while (dataSnapshotsorder .hasNext()) {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshotsChat.next();
            total_amount += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dataSnapshotChild .child("mPrice").getValue()));                  
 }
```

Comment: sorry but the above method is also giving following errors    
    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.eaton/com.example.android.eaton.PlaceOrder}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)`

Comment: thanks I have solved the above error. It was because I was setting a textview with int value. But still I haven't got the right sum of the price if you could help in that regard as well

Comment: post your firebase table structure.